# How to configure web routes and api routes with multiple authentication in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, jwt

I am using laravel 5.8 and preparing an application with multiple interfaces.

**For Example:** I have three types of interfaces like.

1) User Interface (end users)

2) Agencies (inter-mediator user between system and end user)

3) Admin panel

all three having different users and authentication.

Database tables:
1) User Interface: users
2) Agencies: agency_users
3) Admin panel: admins

and different models accordingly.

Now, here I should have web interface for all three. and Rest API for User Interface and Agencies where both should have different API authentication.

I had done lot more search for proper fundamentals of API in laravel but not getting similar kind of information.

Please suggest me if anyone have resolved similar type of scenario. Will provide more information if required.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: On each group of routes (api/web/admin) use middleware to check that certain criteria are met. https://laravel.com/docs/master/middleware

Comment: If you use custom authentication guards (which would probably be the right solution), you can use the built-in middleware with the guard name, e.g. `auth:admin` for an `admin` guard.

Comment: @Namoshek thanks for your suggestion, can you please elaborate more your idea?

Comment: It is quite well explained in the [official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/authentication), specifically [adding custom guards](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/authentication#adding-custom-guards), [adding custom user providers](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/authentication#adding-custom-user-providers) and [protecting routes](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/authentication#protecting-routes) seem very relevant to what you are asking for.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of my own middlewares, it looks if the authenticated user is an admin.

NOTE: be sute to also add your middlware to the HTTP/Kernel.php

```
class IsAdmin
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next) {
        if (Auth::user() &&  Auth::user()->admin == 1) {
            return $next($request);
        }

        return redirect('/');
    }
}
```

After that you can use a RouteGroup in your routes and add your middleware as the middleware of that group